# Do you need to repeat the word "sector" for clarity in this sentence?

Tags: repetition

Is the following sentence okay as is, or is it necessary to repeat the word "sector" to make clear you mean "private sector and public sector organizations."?

> Trust in private and public sector organizations has been shrinking in recent years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Trust in **private** and public sector organizations has been shrinking in recent years.

It's extremely unlikely that anybody would think that you weren't talking about *private sector organizations* in this sentence.

After all, *trust in private* doesn't mean anything and it's natural for us to interpret sentences in a way that they make sense (if we can).

So, it should be fine to leave it as it is.

---

If the sentence had been slightly different, it would be a different matter:

> Trust in **privacy** and public sector organizations has been shrinking in recent years.

Here, it would be much more likely for *privacy* to be taken as something separate. (Mainly because it's common to talk about *privacy* on its own.)

Had it been meant the other way, then making it explicit would be recommended:

> Trust in both privacy sector organizations and public sector organizations has been shrinking in recent years.

(This is assuming that *privacy sector organizations* makes sense and is not a typo for *private*.)